# JQuery Animation on load page and after refreshing website

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to have floating box on the side (for example for shopping basket). It is working fine BUT I dont like when I open the page (in CHROME and IE9)the box animate from top to the position. See www.arturtest.co.uk In Firefox is fine. 
Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(floatSides);
    floatSides();
});

function floatSides () {
    var offset = $(document).scrollTop() + 120;
    $('.floatingBox').animate({top: offset + "px"},{duration:750,queue:false});
}
```

I just want them to appear on the good places like FireFox.

Any ideas.

Comment: You mean you don't want any animation? In that case, just comment out the floatSides(); line?

Comment: Use `.css()` instead of `.animate()`.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick-fix, after the initial call to `floatSides()`, force the animation to complete right away by using `.finish()`. It would look like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(floatSides);
    floatSides();
    $('.floatingBox').finish();
});
```